# Getting error in python code as :"RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise"

Tags: python

I have the below code which should raise exception if numbers are not between 1 to 15. Instead i get below error message if i select a number other than 1 to 15.

Error message:
"RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise"

Can someone please guide me if am using "try" & "except" at a wrong place.

Here is my Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from txt_preprocessing.text_preprocessing import TextPreprocessor as TP


def preprocessing_util_func(csv_file,usr_lst,language='english'):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    lstt = usr_lst
    print(lstt)
    try:
        for i in lstt:
            if i==1:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.tokenize_doc(x,return_var_type="list_tokens"))
            elif i==2:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.remove_stop_words(x,return_var_type="string"))
            elif i==3:
                df['X'] = df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.remove_punctuation(x, return_var_type="string"))
            elif i==4:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.sentencize_doc(x,return_type="list_sentences"))
            elif i==5:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.custom_sentencize_doc(x,return_type="list_sentences"))
            elif i==6:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.case_fold(x))
            elif i==7:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.custom_tokenize_doc(x))
            elif i==8:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.lemmatize_doc(x))
            elif i==9:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.remove_special_characters(x))
            elif i==10:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.remove_non_ascii_characters(x))
            elif i==11:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.remove_custom_stop_words(x,return_var_type="list_tokens"))
            elif i==12:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.remove_numbers(x,return_var_type="list_tokens"))
            elif i==13:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.remove_whitespace(x))
            elif i==14:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.remove_custom_stopphrases(x,custom_stopphrases=['is not','to not']))
            elif i==15:
                df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: TP.remove_custom_portion_text(x))
        except:
            print("Please check the number under lst selection", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
        return df
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong; the "raise" should be tabbed to be under "except".

Answer (score 0):

Yes it there some errors. At the end, it should be:

```py
except:
    print("Please check the number under lst selection",sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
return df
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a try ...except in your case, because there isn’t any [Built-in Exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions) for i other than 1 to 15.
You can achieve your goal by adding
`else:
     raise Exception("Please check the number under lst selection")`
And you can keep the try ...execpt statement to detect other exceptions